# Text is not being rendered after new pages loaded - JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

I have a program that given an SQL statement (browser database using HTML5-SQL), it populates a set of field in my jquery mobile page. The SQL statement is changed based on an ID passed through the url. So when a button/link is clicked, the same page is called with a different parameter value: index.html?id=545.

Although the first page load seamless, when I click the link to the next page, the objects (page, buttons, link, div) show, but the text inside these objects doesn't show up.

I am using the  `$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){` event in order to trigger the events of  doing the following:

```
$("#title").text(Title);
$("#date").text(mdate);
```

When I print the value of Title and mdate in the console of Chrome debugger, it shows the right value. I don't know why the same text doesn't show in the buttons and labels.

Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When using jQM you need to refresh the controls. Here are the docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

> **Refreshing form elements**
>  In jQuery Mobile, some enhanced form controls are simply styled (inputs), but others are custom
>   controls (selects, sliders) built from, and kept in sync with, the
>   native control. To programmatically update a form control with
>   JavaScript, first manipulate the native control, then use the refresh
>   method to tell the enhanced control to update itself to match the new
>   state. Here are some examples of how to update common form controls,
>   then call the refresh method:

**Checkboxes:**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

**Radios:**

```
$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

**Selects:**

```
var myselect = $("#selectfoo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

**Sliders:**

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh");
```

**Flip switches (they use slider):**

```
var myswitch = $("#selectbar");
myswitch[0].selectedIndex = 1;
myswitch.slider("refresh");
```

if it's the page you need, try this:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Enhancing new markup**
>  The page plugin dispatches a pagecreate event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long
>   as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance
>   any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
>   enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

Comment: Hey Phill, Thank for your response. I don't have any special control to refresh. I am only using h4 tags, and link/buttons. The problem is not rendering the graphic. All the objects in term of design are showing up perfectly. I tried to do '$('#pagename').page('refresh'), $('#pagename').listview('refresh'), and $('div').listview('refresh')'  but none of them work after loading the new page. Any other suggestion.

Comment: My page is too big to post the whole thing. I have generated a jsfiddle with the code responsible for the generation of the database, retrieving and printing text to the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/Vb8jE/1/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with the correct version of jQuery and added the jQM CSS and JS in the Manage Resources. Also jQM doesn't use document.ready http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html Here is the updated http://jsfiddle.net/Vb8jE/3/ as I'm not able to connect the the html5sql (database) it's still a challenge to debug. Could you add a little more?

Comment: I am using document.ready because I only want it to be executed on the first load of the page. As I mentioned before this is not the complete page. This is only the code that I have used for the javascript. I will put more in a moment.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle with most of the things that I am using although is only showing the frame in the result windows. http://jsfiddle.net/Vb8jE/11/